# C# XNA 4 How to control in the vertex shader where pixel ends up in the renderTarget?

Tags: xna, position, pixel, hlsl, vertex-shader

what if I have an arbitrary renderTarget, that is smaller than the screen (say it is 1x1 pixel) and I want to make sure in the VertexShaderFunction that all my pixels end up exactly in that 1 pixel region? Nomatter what I do, they all seem to get culled at some point, though GraphicDevise.Clear() works OK.

Where is the top left corner of the renderTarget Vertex-shader-vise? I tried output.Position = (0,0,0,0)/(0,0,0,1)/(1,1,1,1)/(-0.5,0.5,0,1) NOTHING works!

Fullscreen quad is not an option cuz I actually need to process geometry in the shaders to get the results I need.

Comment: This won't work. A vertex shader doesn't have a concept of "pixels" or even "triangles". If you move all the vertices into one place you will get no output. If you spread the vertices out (somehow - it would be very convoluted) - then you've just ended up with a full-screen quad.

Comment: Just to keep things linked up, [here's the same question on the gamedev site](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/59850/288).